# How do you set CSS property values when another element is active in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a no JavaScript light switch. One of the issues I'm having is the fact that I don't know how to set a property of something else while one thing is <kbd>:active</kbd>. I've been trying a few things, but nothing is working. I have the CodePen right [here](https://codepen.io/ReallyBadDeveloper/pen/wvQrjEd). Otherwise, here's some code:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.wall-switch {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 22px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset 10px 10px 22px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.screw {
  padding: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 2.5px 2.5px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), inset -2.5px -2.5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30), 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}

.icon {
  transition-duration: 10s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.icon:active {
  transform: rotate(-3600deg);
}

.padding {
  padding: 55px;
}

.switch {
  width: 105px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40), inset 0px 95px 20px 0px #ebebeb, inset 0px -95px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.switch:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40), inset 0px -95px 20px 0px #6b6b6b, inset 0px 95px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.switch:active .wall-switch {
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
}
```

```html
<div class="wall-switch">
  <div class="screw">
    <svg class="icon  icon--plus" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)">
        <path d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z" stroke="url(#grad1)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="padding"></div>
  <div class="switch"></div>
  <div class="padding"></div>
  <div class="screw">
    <svg class="icon  icon--plus" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)">
        <path d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z" stroke="url(#grad1)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know of a solution? I've been working on this for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked it up, turns out its a new feature in css. The > character is for ascension (child to parent, which is new).

```
.wall-switch:has(> .switch:active){
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
}
```

Reference: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958)

Comment: I saw a post that said that `:has()` was deprecated, but from a little researching, I found otherwise. Thanks!